# Can't select * using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I'm selecting data in string variable using awk, but if I try to select '*', it doesn't get selected correctly. How can i solve this problem?

Example:

```
test=`echo "data * data" | awk '{split($0,d," "); print d[2]}'`
```

Then I echo:

```
echo $test
```

I expect it to show "*", but it doesn't.

Thanks.

Comment: `echo "data * data" | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: Does it instead show a list of the files in the current directory, similar to if you typed `echo *`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use quotes:

```
echo "$test"
```

Otherwise, the shell is expanding the '*' as a glob and passing the names of all the files in the current directory to echo.

Comment: Addind " to echo "data * data" and " to echo "$test" solved the problem. Thank you.